# How can I force 1.8.0_191 ( x86_64) just for this application (JNLP)?

Tags: java, windows, java-web-start, jnlp

How can I force 1.8.0_191 ( x86_64) just for this application?

JNLP file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" 
        codebase="https://site/vpef/auxiliary/jar/"
        href="app.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>APP</title>
        <vendor>IT</vendor>
        <homepage href="https://site"/>
        <description>TEST APP</description>
    </information>
    <resources>
                <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.8.0+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" java-vm-args="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms2g -Xmx6g -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"/>
        <jar href="MainPane_x64.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <applet-desc name="APP" main-class="app1.Pane.MainPane" width="250" height="200">
    </applet-desc>
    <update check="always" policy="always"/>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
</jnlp>
```

Installed java versions:

```
1.8          1.8.0_231            http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se         C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin\javaw.exe -Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11           true       x86

1.8          1.8.0_191            http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se         C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\javaw.exe  -Xmx8g true       x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put a specific Java build into the jnlp file; e.g.

```
<j2se version="1.8.0_191" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" 
      java-vm-args="....."/>
```

At least ... that is what [the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/jnlp-file-syntax.htm#GUID-F32AB01F-C9AF-4D7B-B9CB-66ACE2771846) says.

Comment: still same issue btw Installed java versions both 32 bit and 64 bit 

https://imgur.com/a/t3hto3s

Comment: What "same issue" are you talking about?  Do you mean that JWS is (apparently) ignoring the what the `<j2se>` element says?  (If so, how do you know that?)  Or that the problem you were trying to cure by using a specific build is not fixed?